# Ajax load data once

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below is my code I used to load some data when click on my divplease advice

```
$('#data).on('click', function () {

});

function searchData(section) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/user/getresults',
        data: {q: section},
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data;
            if (result.success) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: according to your code the result should always be the same

Answer (score 1):

Try to put following lines inside success handler

```
 var $resultList = $('.search--results');
 $resultList.html('');
```

EDIT:
Have you changed it to:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/user/getresults',
                data: {q: section},
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = data;
                    if (result.success) {
                       var $resultList = $('.search--results');
                       $resultList.html('');
                       //putting data inside element
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: But if fails, the previous result will still be shown which will lead confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple calls, add below line to your first click function, but still your code may be executing per clicks where you may need to have overlay on page or some spinner that covers whole page to avoid  multiple clicks

```
//Prevent form submission
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Will be together:

```
$('#search').live('click', function (e) {
   searchData(section);
   //Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appear to need a closing single-quote after `#data`.

My suggestion is to clean the script and it might work.

**HTML**

```
...
<div id="data">...</div>
...
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#data').on('click', function(evt) {
    searchData('query string');
});

function searchData(section) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/user/getresults',
        data: {
            q: section
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                console.log("data from response" + data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The question did have single quote there when was posted, after the question got changed it was gone.